# Reroute all internet traffic to RRAS VPN server and redirect through proxy

Tags: networking, router, vpn, proxy, routing

What i am try to do is to reroute all internet traffic at router to a local server, and proxy the traffics from router by a application on server, the app will encrypted and redirect to remote server.
The reason i do this is to create a global proxy behind my router, that all the devices traffic will go through the proxy server without doing any configuration on each devices. Since my router not support reroute traffic to proxy server, the only option i have is connect a VPN at router to my local server, and then process those VPN traffics through proxy application.

My question:

1. I was finished to setup a RRAS VPN at my local server and no problem to access the server resource by VPN connection, but the internet traffic won’t go through the server.
2. Another issue is, even i figure out how to get through the internet traffic on server, how to redirect those traffic through local port that my proxy app is listening.

The proxy application i use:
[Clash for Windows](https://github.com/Dreamacro/clash)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.